# How do tell 2 different types of input apart?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

```
while(letter!='e'){
        scanf(" %c %i %i",&letter,&xPos,&yPos);
        grid[xPos][yPos] = 1;
    }
```

I want the loop to end when `letter ='e';`.
 I need to input `e` twice to end the loop.
 I know that my `scanf` expects the 2 integers as well, and that this somehow mankes me to need to input `e` twice. How do i fix this?

Comment: Add this at the end `scanf(" %c", &letter);`

Comment: Separate the `scanf` into two calls, the first being `scanf(" %c", &letter)`, and test `letter` before calling the second `scanf`, `scanf("%i%i", &xPos, &yPos)`. Also test the return value of `scanf`. In the future, provide a [mre] with questions like this.

Comment: Second_Impact, use `fgets()` to read a _line_ of input.   Parse with `sscanf(" %c %i %i",...`.  Note the return value.  If 1 and letter is `'e'`, stop.  Best to stop using `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the sample program below to rectify your doubt. For the most part, you don't have to worry about the \n, because scanf() is programmed in such a way that it would skip any interleaving white space (which includes \n). Although, knowledgeable people say that it's better if you assume that scanf() reads the format exactly as it is typed. The problem is that %c behaves differently. Reading from the manual about %c, it says:
The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.
To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format.

So really to fix this call and the program, you just add that explicit space:
scanf(" %c", &o);

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
char letter;
int xPos,yPos;
int grid[3][3]={{0}};
while(letter !='e'){
    printf("enter letter\n");
    scanf(" %c",&letter);
    if(letter=='e')
    break;    // here break is used to immediately end the program after entering 'e' as per your requirement
    printf("enter xpos and ypos\n");
    scanf(" %i  %i",&xPos,&yPos);
    grid[xPos][yPos] = 1;
    
}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("%d",grid[i][j]);
    }printf("\n");
}
}
```